# Parsing property name and value from ksoap response

Tags: android, ksoap2

So I've got my WebService connected to my Android app without any problems, and can get responses without any problems but I wanted to know if there's any way to get the Property name of the SoapObject as well as the value, instead of just getting the value?

For example I get this response (this is a very simple response just for a sample)

```
anyType{AsOfDate=2014-02-12T12:58:27-08:00; StatusID=9; }
```

Now when parsing I wanted to be able to take the values from my response and then create a List (like a NSDictionary) so I can have a key/value pair like :

```
AsOfDate = 2014-02-12T12:58:27-08:00;
StatusID = 9;
```

But so far I haven't been able to narrow down how I can get the property name when parsing, here's what I have so far:

```
SoapObject errortable = (SoapObject)dataset.getProperty("ErrorTable");
                for (int i = 0; i < errortable.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
                    Object object = errortable.getProperty(i);
                    //Log.d(ENSI_DEBUG, "the object is: " + object.getClass());
                    if (object instanceof SoapObject) {
                        Log.d(ENSI_DEBUG, "the object is a soap object = " + object);
                    }
                    if (object instanceof SoapPrimitive) {
                        Log.d(ENSI_DEBUG, "the object contains value: " + object.toString() + " and name: " //here's where I would like to get the property name to create the key/value pair );
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem, I needed to use the Property Info object to get the name, so I ended up using this code below to get what I needed.

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject) response.getProperty("result");
        SoapObject diffgram = (SoapObject) result.getProperty("diffgram");
        SoapObject dataset = (SoapObject) diffgram.getProperty("NewDataSet");
        for (int j = 0; j < dataset.getPropertyCount(); j++) {
            SoapObject finalObject = (SoapObject) dataset.getProperty(j);
            for (int i = 0; i < finalObject.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
                Object object = finalObject.getProperty(i);
                PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
                finalObject.getPropertyInfo(i, propertyInfo);
                if (object instanceof SoapPrimitive) {
                    hashMap.put(propertyInfo.name, object.toString());
                }
            }
            dataList.add(hashMap);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample code.It works for me.

```
           if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapObject) { // SoapObject =
                                                            // SUCCESS
                SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
                int count = response.getPropertyCount();
                Log.i("count", Integer.toString(count));

                int StatusID= Integer.parseInt(response
                        .getPropertyAsString("StatusID"));
                Log.i("StatusID", Integer.toString(StatusID));
                String AsOfDate= (response
                        .getPropertyAsString("AsOfDate"));
                Log.i("AsOfDate", AsOfDate);

            }
```